# Node js displaying images from server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to display an image on a basic web page on a localhost w/ port 5000
here is main.js

```
var http = require('http');

var domain = require('domain');

var root = require('./root');
var image = require('./image');



function replyError(res) {

  try {

    res.writeHead(500);

    res.end('Server error.');

  } catch (err) {

    console.error('Error sending response with code 500.');

  }

};



function replyNotFound(res) {

  res.writeHead(404);

  res.end('not found');

}



function handleRequest(req, res) {

  console.log('Handling request for ' + req.url);

  if (req.url === '/') {

    root.handle(req, res);

  } else if (req.url === '/image.png'){

    image.handle(req, res);

  } else {

    replyNotFound(res);

  }

}



var server = http.createServer();



server.on('request', function(req, res) {

  var d = domain.create();

  d.on('error', function(err) {

    console.error(req.url, err.message);

    replyError(res);

  });

  d.run(function() { handleRequest(req, res); });

});



function CallbackToInit(){

  server.listen(5000);
};
root.init(CallbackToInit);
```

Using callbacks I want the server to start listening(5000) only after the init function of the following code runs

```
var http = require('http');

var body;

exports.handle = function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  });
  res.end(body);
};

exports.init = function(cb) {
  require('fs').readFile('image.png', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    body = data;
    cb();
  });
}
```

It's an assignment I can't use express

I am trying to get image.png to be displayed, I think body = data doesn't work because it can't hold an image like a string? I don't want to put any HTML into my js file.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  Is there something that's not working how you'd expect?  An error?

Comment: yeah image.png isn't displaying. I assume because body can't hold an image like it does a string?? in the developer tools it's not even listed as a resource

Comment: What if you directly navigate to `image.png`?  Can you try changing the content-type?  The `text/html` probably isn't helping.  `image/png` would be appropriate, I believe.

Comment: oh it's already on image/png I forgot to change that before I posted sorry. I would prefer not to res.write(html for image). I'm not supposed to use html code

Comment: oh wait it looks like my handle function isn't firing oO

Comment: omg haha i figured it out, that's why it wasn't working because it wasn't firing.

Comment: So the second block of code is `image.js`, right?  It doesn't look like you're calling `image.init` anywhere.  Unless `root.init` is doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the node.js example for a simple http server](http://nodejs.org/) or a tutorial/example, such as [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/serving-static-files-with-node-js/), for serving static files through a simple server.

Comment: well i have error statements but my shit does get fired I adde console.log to the functions and the init and handle functions are being fired

Comment: I must've missed some of your code then, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't roll your own app server. Use one of the great web app frameworks like [express](http://expressjs.com) or [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect).

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Trust me, this is better.